# Question regarding r's complement

Tags: elementary-number-theory, number-systems

This question was asked in a test in my undergrad course

> A computer, using 3-digit radix complement arithmetic with an unknown
> radix r, gives the following results expressed in radix complement
> form:
>
> (m + n)<sub>r</sub> = (087)<sub>r</sub>; (m − n)<sub>r</sub> = (005)<sub>r</sub>  ; (n − m)<sub>r</sub> = (184)<sub>r</sub>
>
> Identify the radix r and the decimal values of m and n.

This is what I did:

> Adding last 2 equations,
>
> (m-n+n-m)<sub>r</sub> = (005)<sub>r</sub> + (184)<sub>r</sub>
>
> -> 0 = (005)<sub>r</sub> + (184)<sub>r</sub>
>
> -> 0 = 5*r<sup>0</sup> + 1*r<sup>2</sup> + 8*r<sup>1</sup> + 4*r<sup>0</sup>
>
> Because this equation has no integer solutions, therefore no valid r exists.

Am I correct?

Comment: Can someone please answer this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that in $3$-digit $r$'s complement, $-x$ is the complement with respect to $r^3$. Let $x = m-n$

$x = (005)_r$

$-x = (184)_r$

$r^3 = 1\cdot r^2 + 8 \cdot r + 9$

Since $-x$ has a $8$ in it, we have $r\ge 8+1$. But then it will not satisfy our derived equation.

Perhaps there was a typo in the exam?

Comment: Sir says that in radix complement representation, the MSB has a negative place value. So that 184 = -1*r^2 + 8*r + 9. Is that true?